# Share and access a 2-dimensional array between processes

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, process, shared-memory

I have a 2-dimensional array of a structure `Data`, that has to be initialized. The main program creates 1 server and 4 clients. All the processes should be able to access and modify the data (I already took care of synchronization problems using semaphores). Every part of the program is located in a separate .c file. How can I initialize, share, and access / modify my data (how can I access the fields of the structure, in `server()` or `client()`) ? I'm currently using System V but could use Posix if more appropriate.

```
/*  project.h   */
typedef struct Data {
    int fieldA;
    int fieldB;
    int fieldC;
    int fieldD;
} Data;

extern Data data[4][3];
extern int shm;
extern Data *p;
```

```
/*  main.c  */
#include "project.h"

Data *p;
int shm;

void main()
{
    int i;

    shm = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 3*4*sizeof(Data), 0666);
    p = (Data *) shmat(shm, NULL, 0);

    for (i=1;i<5;i++) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            client(i);
        }
    }

    if (fork() == 0) {
        server();
    }
}
```

```
/*  server.c    */
#include "project.h"

// I only care about the first field of Data when I initialize.
Data data[4][3] = { {{0},{1},{-1}},
                    {{2},{-1},{-1}},
                    {{5},{0},{3}},
                    {{-1},{6},{-1}} };

void server()                   
{
    /*  read / modify the data  */
}
```

```
/*  client.c    */
#include "project.h"

void client(int i)                  
{
    /*  read / modify the data  */
}
```

Comment: can we assume the various processes are all being created in a single executable?

Comment: there needs to be some more header files.  one for the client(s) (client.h) that contains the prototype for the client function.  one for the server (server.h) that contains the prototype for the server function.   both of those header files need to be included in the main.c file.  the client.c file needs to include the client.h file.  the server.c file needs to include the server.h file.

Comment: since the main.c file does not use the data[][] array and actually creates the *p and shm variables, suggest main.c not include the 'project.h' file.  Suggest the project.h file contain #defines for the row and column sizes and client/server files use those #defines rather than hardcoded 'magic' numbers.

Comment: @user3629249 I don't understand your question. All the processes are created by the main program. Since I tried to simplify the code for the post, I forgot to mention that I do have all the other .h files you mention. In my original code, `main.c` needs to include `project.h` for other purposes.